# How to Handle Image upload / capture image via camera in mobile

Tags: php, ajax, forms, jquery-mobile

I have web app with multiple forms, each form collect different information. 
Once of form opening popup bootstrap modal window and upload image and after submit it upload via Ajax call After image upload and copy image name to another form input area.

This working perfectly on desktop browsers but it is not working in mobile phone browser.

When I select image via camera it submit and redirecting page.

**Note:**
What I need is: if I select image via camera and select it then it should not redirect or auto submit it should work like desktop web browser.

**SELECT IMAGE FORM:**

```
<tr><td>PHOTO</td><td><input type='text' class='upload' id='photo' readonly='readonly' /><button id='upImage' class='upImage' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#image_upload' data-backdrop='static' data-keyboard='false'>Click me</button>*Max 1MB, JPG / PNG</td></tr>
```

**POPUP Image upload form:**

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="uploadForm" method="post" >

<div class="upitem2">
<label>Upload Image File:</label><br/>
<input name="userImage" type="file" class="inputFile" accept='image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif'/>
</div>
<div class="upitem3">
<input type="submit" value="Submit"  class="btn btn-default" />
</div>
</form>
      </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

**AJAX form Submit and set value back to main form**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (e) {
  $("#uploadForm").on('submit',(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
          url: "fileUpload.php",
      type: "POST",
      data:  new FormData(this),
      contentType: false,
          cache: false,
      processData:false,
       async: false,
      success: function(data)
        {

          data = data;
      //$("#targetLayer").html(data);
      //$("#targetLayer").attr("src", data);
      $("#photo").val(data);
      //console.log(data);
        },
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

alert( console.log(jqXHR) + console.log(textStatus) +  console.log(errorThrown));
        //alert('An error occurred... Please Contact to Admin');
  //alert('Please upload Below 1MB Image and it');
            }
     });
  }));
});
</script>
```

**Note:** 
There is another form which is not related to this but only convert all data and save to database.

is there any special function for mobile to work above code like normal desktop?